# Sequelize validate throws [object object] error

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying out Sequelize's built in validators. Model definition:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
var Device = sequelize.define('Device', {
    model_name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      validate: {
        notNull: {
          args: true,
          msg: 'Model name needed'
        }
      }
    }
    ...
```

with `bulkCreate`

```
Device.bulkCreate(csvOutput, { validate: true })
  .then(function() {
    console.log('Records inserted into database')
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log('Error encountered: ' + err.message)
  })
```

To test, I tried to insert a blank field for `model_name`. I tried also to include a proper model name.

Both scenarios above produce an error that is simply `[object Object]`. I could not seem to figure out why. Hope someone can shed some light here!

Note: the error goes away if i remove `validate` from the Model entirely.

Comment: `args` should be an array of allowed values of column. In your case there is no need to `args` prop, try to delete it

Comment: @TilekbekovYrysbek I tried `notNull: true` directly (without msg) but that did not work either

Comment: just change validate to it `notNull: {msg: 'Model name needed'}`

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, and i'm posting it here in case this could be helpful to anyone.

Changing this line `console.log('Error encountered: ' + err.message)` to just `console.log(err)` allows the error message to display properly on the console.

The string concatenation prevents the error message from showing (allowing only `[object Object]` to be displayed).

With the error message, the problem became obvious **the validation `notNull` is deprecated** and should be replaced by the column attribute `allowNull` (note this is a column attribute, not a validator)